# MATLAB:imcontrast for subplot

Tags: matlab, figure, contrast

I want to use imcontrast for several images in one figure which is drawed by subplot. There is similar question but it wasn't answered:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/160315-how-to-adjust-contrast-of-a-figure-with-3-subplots-simultaneously

In the answer of this question, he suggested usage of imadjust. It is not proper for my case because I'm opening saved fig files. Is there any way for my case like the question asked?

Comment: If you're opening the figure again, recalling subplot should let you switch between the different figures. For a 2-by-2, `subplot(2,2,1); imcontrast(); subplot(2,2,2); imcontrast; subplot(2,2,3); imcontrast; subplot(2,2,4); imcontrast;` should work unless there's something I don't know about imcontrast

Comment: I tried what you said but it is not working. It is changing only third image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to call `imcontrast(h)` for each subplot. Once the figure is open, `h1 = subplot(1,2,1); imcontrast(h1);` allowed me to edit the first subplot.

I tested using the following code:

```
subplot(1,2,1); imshow('coins.png');
subplot(1,2,2); imshow('coins.png');
h1 = subplot(1,2,1); 
imcontrast(h1);
```

Comment: Ok. However in my situation, I saved all the figures without using h=subplot(1,2,1). Is it not possible to do this without having the h handle?

Comment: Does reopening the figure and then using the h1 command not work?

Comment: I got it. I will try. Thanks Ian!

Comment: I had limited license access yesterday- if this still doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll look into it more